What are the certchain.pem and private.key files used by Pythons ssl library, are they required, and how can I create them if they are?
Background
I am writing a Python utility which will allow synchronization of files and folders across a network between a client machine and a server. Synchronization will be unidirectional and initiated by a client push action.
The initial "version 1" for this is quite simple. The server will be in an "always on" (listening) state, and will listen for connections from a client.
The client will be run from the command line. (Hence "push action".) When run, the client will connect to the server, perform some form of authentication (most likely based on private/public key pairs or alternatively username and password) and then send each file in a target directory to the server.
The server will write the recieved files to a (different) target directory.
Security
In order for this to be secure, either the entire session has to be protected by encryption, or the secure data has to be send encrypted. In this case, the secure data is a private key or username and password, and then the contents of each file.
The best way to achieve security
I do not know what the best way to achieve security is. One simple "roll your own" solution would be to pre-agree an encryption key between the client and server, and use this encryption key to encrypt and decrypt data. This could be done in a manual way by simply writing the code to do it.
The most straightforward way would probably be to use a standard encryption/decryption library. A quick search suggests the Python cryptography library is probably the standard go-to solution.
Although, more manual solutions would be possible, such as performing an xor operation between a 256 bit key and the data. I'm not sure how secure this would be, certainly it would be less secure than using a standard implementation.
However, it seems that a better approach might be to use Python's ssl library, which provides TSL 1.3 on top of the standard sockets library.
I do not know if this will be a suitable solution. The library (like all Python libraries) is quite high level. It is difficult to know what it is doing and how it works from the examples provided in the documentation.
Python ssl
I started to write an example client-server application in Python which uses the ssl library.
There is one line on the server side code which I do not understand.
context.load_cert_chain('/path/to/certchain.pem', '/path/to/private.key')

I don't know that much about how certificates work. I know that these two files are used to encrypt the ssl session and to give the client guarantees that the server is who it claims to be. (In other words, it provides a guarantee, somehow, that your traffic has not been intercepted and forwarded to a malicious server which is pretending to be the legitimate one.)
I don't really need the second of these features. Due to the network infrastructure ontop of which this client-server application will run, there is no need to perform a check to ensure the server is the server it claims to be. This will all effectively be running over a virtual private network. I probably don't really need to encrypt the data for this reason, but this is one security feature we do want to have, even though debatably it isn't needed.

Is there a way to use Python's ssl library to provide encryption but without having to load the certificate and private key files?

I decided to provide a lot of detail in this question, because it could be that I am going in completely the wrong direction here. It might be that the ssl library isn't the right thing to use. It just seemed like it might be a convenient solution.

"I know that these two files are used to encrypt the ssl session" - That's wrong. These files are used for authentication. Encryption is instead done with symmetric encryption with keys from the key exchange in the TLS handshake. The RSA key exchange also needs certificates, but its long obsolete and DHE/ECDHE (diffie-gelman key exchange) does not use certificates.

"Is there a way to use Python's ssl library to provide encryption but without having to load the certificate and private key files?" - authentication of the peer is integral part of TLS. TLS 1.2 and lower would support "NULL" authentication, but not with modern TLS 1.3. If you really want to skip authentication use self-signed certificates but don't verify - which is about as insecure as not encrypting at all.

@SteffenUllrich Isn't this nit-picking? These are static files. Clients authenitcate who they are by providing some information not stored on the server. (eg username and pass)

Server certificates are about server authentication, i.e. making sure that the client talks to the expected server and not someone impersonating the server (or a man-in-the-middle). Encryption does not help if you encrypt with the wrong party.

@SteffenUllrich I don't agree with your second (and third) comment either. Yes, in theory it may be possible for someone to write a copy of my server application which behaves in the same way as my own version of the code. But this is extremely unlikely. They would also have to perform a MITM attack. It's possible it's just not within the realm of things that can actually be done.

@SteffenUllrich what I am looking for here is a reasonable level of security. Not the best possible security. There's a lot of information in the context I provided. If you read it - you will see

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
